# Custom MS Botframework ActivityHandler in a Composer-Project

Tags: botframework

I attempt to bring proactivity into a chatbot created with MS Botframework Composer. The "Composer"-part is essential here.
Presumably I have to work with something similar to the example given in https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages.
However I realize that if I register the `ProactiveBot` (which extends `ActivityHandler`) in the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class, i.e. `services.AddTransient<IBot, ProactiveBot>();` then the dialog defined via Composer is never run. I only get the simple dialog defined in `ProactiveBot`.
It seems to me, I need to use an `ActivityHandler` to be able to collect the `ConversationReference`.

So my question is:

- Is there another, Composer-compatible way, to access the conversation references in code?
- If I need to do this via `ActivityHandler`, how do I enable the Composer-defined dialog to run?

Thanks!

Update:

- I am exploring the option to consume a skill in the Composer-bot. Since schema version 2.1 a skill may be proactive.